# toLocaleDateString() in Chrome returns the wrong date

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Running the code beneath on google-chrome 45.0.2454.99 m:

```js
var date = new Date(1500,10,11)

date.setHours(12) // Important to avoid changing the day after localization

document.write(date + "<br>");
document.write(date.toString() + "<br>");
document.write(date.toDateString() + "<br>");
document.write(date.toLocaleDateString() + "<br>");
```

It returns:

```
Sun Nov 11 1500 12:00:00 GMT-0200 // 11/11/1500
Sun Nov 11 1500 12:00:00 GMT-0200 // 11/11/1500
Sun Nov 11 1500 // 11/11/1500
01/11/1500 // -- This one differs from the others above
```

Can anyone explain me why and how to fix this problem?

Comment: can u try moment js?  it would resolve your issue

Comment: It wont occur on Firefox 34.0.5

Comment: I'll give it a try, thank you @achan

Comment: Can this be a bug since it doesn't happen on Firefox and IE?

Comment: Opened a bug on code.google.com: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=537382

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really was a bug, corrected in December 8th, 2015
https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8.git/+/d67756a7753e322fdd986399677a45a0459a5d40

Comment: This SO question is a comment in the V8 source code for format-test.js https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/test/intl/date-format/format-test.js#L48